# csv to pandas.DataFrame while keeping data original encoding

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-unicode

I have a `csv` file with some `utf8` unicode characters in it, which I want to load into a `pandas.DataFrame` while keeping the unicode characters as is, not escaping them.

Input `.csv`:

```
letter,unicode_primary,unicode_alternatives
8,\u0668,"\u0668,\u06F8"
```

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("file.csv")
print(df.loc[0].unicode_primary)
```

Result:

`> \\u0668`

Desired Result:

`> \u0668`

or

`> 8`

Answer (score -1):

Please use read_csv instead of from_csv as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.csv", encoding = 'utf_8'))
print(df.loc[0].unicode_primary)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this doesn't work. Same behavior

Comment: @A_Matar, I had trouble using from_csv, as it by default used the first column as index, and hence the df.loc[0] threw an error u'the label [0] is not in the [index]'. With read_csv, the default index will be None and it will create a new index. I could execute the df.loc[0] after using read_csv.  I am using Python 2.7.14 and pandas 0.22.0

Comment: great, but this doesn't answer my original question; I need to read the unicode characters as unicode characters not as escaped strings.
P.s. you can use `index=False` with `from_csv` to remove the index column. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: @A_Matar, can you please try the parameter,  encoding : str, , available in the read_csv?